# Serializing Events into JSON

Tags: c#, button, events, serialization, action

I am working on a serialization system using Json, but I need to save events from Buttons (onClick, onHover, etc.) Is there a way about doing this efficiently? (NOTE: The events are all Actions)

Comment: The answer is ***yes***. However you need to read [ask] and add a lot more information to this question

Comment: @MichaelRandall I think the answer is "no", but... I agree there are huge gaps in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly, it is is *terrible idea* to try to serialize events.

JSON is usually used to serialize *data*; events are not data - they are implementation details. Most JSON serializers (or more broadly: most *serializers*) are not interested in delegates / events, because that *isn't relevant to data*, so: there's a good chance that anything you'd want to do here will need to be manual. Specifically, the problem here is that an *event* (or rather, the underlying multicast delegate) is effectively zero, one, or multiple pairs of "instance" (optional) and "method" (required).

The *method* here is a `MethodInfo`, and there aren't great ways to serialize a `MethodInfo` as text (although it is at least theoretically possible, although it would be very brittle vs changes to your code.

The *instance*, however, is an `object` - and most serializers *hate* that; in this case, it would combine object (reference) tracking, possibly of objects *not otherwise inside the payload*, of indeterminate types (so: possibly needing to store type metadata).

Also, deserializing an object model that allows you to point to arbitrary types and methods is a **massive** security hole, and is a well-known RCE weakness in serializers that (unwisely, IMO) allow this kind of thing (such as `BinaryFormatter`; for a longer discussion of this topic, [see here](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2020/03/why-do-i-rag-on-binaryformatter.html)).

---

As for what to do *instead*: whenever an implementation isn't a great fit for a given serializer, the *most pragmatic option* is to stop fighting the serializer, and work *with it* instead of against it. For example, it might be that you can create a model that looks *kinda like* your domain model, but instead of having events/delegates, it might just have a `string[]` / `List<string>` that represents the events you need to apply, and **your code** would worry about how to map between them (mapping methods to strings, and figuring out what the target instance should be, etc). This avoids *all* of the pain points above, and additionally means that your data is now platform independent, with the payload and the implementation details (your form layout) separate from each-other.

Comment: I guess the "Mapping as a List<string>" will be my only option for the use-case. Thank you for helping!